# Ember - how to represent this json in a model

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm an ember newbie.. and have been given a spec that says the server will be sending me the following json:

```
{
   "classname": "class1",
   "studentSummary": [
       {
           "firstName": "test",
           "lastName": "test",
           "score": "45",
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to represent this as a model and create fixture data to work with it...

I understand how to create a model with the multiple records are all the same....

```
var students =  DS.Model.extend({

    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    score: DS.attr('number')

});
```

Which would correspond to a bunch of students like this, right?:

```
{
  [
     {
           "firstName": "test",
           "lastName": "test",
           "score": "45",
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

Or would it?
I'm googleing like mad but don't know if I should be looking at 'embedding' or 'hasMany' or what....
I'm thinkling the hasMany won't work without id's...

So, any push in the right direction would be appreciated...

Thanks
Vida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are embedded records (or so they're called). Your data doesn't have a unique identifier and it belongs only to it's parent record, so moving the data to its own model would be overkill. Embedded records are a sore subject in the Ember-Data community, but there are solutions. [Here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) is the official EmbeddedRecordsMixin and [here](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments) is a project that makes it easier to work with. Either of those should help you out.

If you're having trouble with those, you might want to consider writing a custom [Transform](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html) for your data. It's more low-level, but it gives you more control and its easier to understand (I think).

Comment: Upvoting the answer but a little more to add: In case you want to also write (Create/update) an embedded record then you should move the data to its own model. That is a student model with a belongsTo relationship to the class.

Comment: Thanks very much, thats got me on the right track now.